# GetCurrentProcessID could not be found in kernel32

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have this code here

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function GetCurrentProcessID : Cardinal; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

begin
  writeln (GetCurrentProcessID);
  readln;
end.
```

and it shows me that the entrypoint of `GetCurrentProcessID` could not be found. Any idea why?

I even tried

```
function GetCurrentProcessID : Cardinal; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll'; name 'GetCurrentProcessID';
```

with no luck either...

Comment: Why are you redeclaring the Windows API?

Comment: @RobKennedy Cause I don't need the whole `Windows.pas`

Comment: So what? You already have it. And besides, the compiler doesn't include the entire unit in your binary anyway. It hadn't done that since, like, Turbo Pascal 4. Back when that changed, it was called the "smart linker." Now, that's simply the way everyone expects all linkers to behave, so we just call it the "linker."

Comment: And if you are going to do this, it would be much more reliable to use the clipboard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The name of the function in kernel32 is `GetCurrentProcessId`, note the lower case 'd'.

Comment: Thank you very much! 4 eyes are better than 2. I probably wouldn't have never found it...

Comment: You can find the exact name yourself with `Dependencies (x64)` [https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/]